# download image from link with discord.js then delete the file

Tags: fs, discord.js

I need to download an image from imgur then send it, then delete the file using fs or any other module you may recommend. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to send the image you don't need to save and then delete the file: you can just put the URL in the file option of the message, since it accepts [`BufferResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/BufferResolvable) (and so URLs) too.

```js
let image = "https://discordapp.com/assets/c4bae281354a2b4e2db85415955e0994.svg"; // this is the URL for your image
let channel = message.channel; // this is your channel (I assumed this is in a command)

channel.send("", { file: image }); // you can send the image like this
channel.send("Description message", { file: image }); // you can also set a description
```

Comment: Imgur doesn't seem to support this anymore as images just show as an embed with the title

Comment: Weird... which link are you using? The direct link?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with the module nightmare and nightmare-screenshot-selector. Nightmare is a module used for web-scraping and nightmare-screenshot-selector makes it easier to screenshot different things.

The steps you should do:

```
nightmare
  .goto(url) //imgur.com/xyz
  .wait(#pic) // wait for the picture to load
  .screenshotSelector(#image) //screenshot the image
  .then(function(data) {
    fs.writeFileSync(path, data);  //save the file
    message.channel.send("", {    //send the picture in the channel
      file: path
    });
    fs.unlink(path, (err) => {  //delete the file
     if (err) throw err;
      console.log(path + ' was deleted');
    });
   });
```

Be aware that copy and pasting that code won't probably work you should look at the documentation of the modules and try understanding what you are doing.